# Flutter: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, dart

Hello i have a problem when i compile with flutter

I have already tried to debug with flutter run -- debug but no success
I think that from gradle but i don't know how to fix this.

```
    Resolving dependencies...                                           
    3,5s

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
    > Failed to generate v1 signature

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info 
    or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 4s
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         
    5,2s
    Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

when i run flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, v1.7.4-pre.27, on Microsoft Windows [version 
10.0.17763.503], locale fr-FR)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 
28.0.3)
[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2017 
15.9.12)
X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop development with C++" workload, and include these components:
    MSBuild
    VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 latest v141 tools
    Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763.0)
  [√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
  [√] VS Code (version 1.35.0)
  [√] Connected device (1 available)

  ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Please help me 
Thank you for your time and attention.

Answer (score 14):

run `flutter clean` in terminal and run again

Comment: it still works for 2022

Answer (score 3):

Delete this file : ~/.android/debug.keystore

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

1. run `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get` get all dependency

**Solution 2**

add Multidex

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 15 
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
}
...


dependencies {
   implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
}
```

**Solution 3**

delete `~/.android/debug.keystore` in android sdk.

Note: Follow step wise, only try Solution 3 if above two doest work.

Comment: none of these worked :(

Answer (score 0):

For me, i was able to run app by commenting release code from android/app/build.gradle file

```
//      signingConfigs {
//        release {
//            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
//            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
//            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
//            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
//        }
//    }
//    buildTypes {
//        release {
//            minifyEnabled true 
//             shrinkResources true
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
//        }
//    }
```

Uncomment with:

```
//Debug
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
    //Debug
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

1. Run `flutter clean`
2. Get packages using `flutter pub get`
3. Run again