# create the new flutter project and straight away to build the project

Tags: android, flutter, intellij-idea, java-8

i install jdk 8u292 intellij 2021.2.2 flutter 2.5.3 android-sdk 1.6_r1 (zip file), create the new flutter project and straight away to build the project, but it's unsuccess to build up project

[intellij's console display error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3U0e.png)

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70122055/edit) your post to include the output of [flutter doctor](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#run-flutter-doctor)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035970/invalid-keystore-problem

Try this.

Comment: Check solutions from similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56516311/2000323 You can also run Gradel build with `--debug` option to get more verbode output:  `gradlew build --debug`.

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter doctor` from terminal and it will tell you what to do.

As others mentioned in the comments, the keystore is a often config problem.